# Saying that some action is optional

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am trying to find phrase or word which would properly cover following statement:

> You can bring back the book tomorrow if you like, and if not it is fine.

I am trying to find a way to same that some action is optional, and if not done it will not have repercussions including hurt feelings. Hope my question makes sense.

**Edit:** a better explanation is that I am looking for a word similar to *optional* but implying it must be done in the future; that it can be procrastinated.

Comment: Word to describe phenomenon, pure curiosity since I assume that English has word to cover this usage. Word similar to `optional` but implying it must be done in the future, that it can be procrastinated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two other common phrases:

> Return the book *at some point in the future.*
>
> Return the book *at your leisure/convenience.*

Answer (score 3):

A single word used colloquially, but not in writing, is *whenever*.

> Bring the book back whenever.

This is understood to mean "whenever you like" (which is how it would appear in writing).

Answer (score 1):

‘You can bring back the book tomorrow if you want to, but I’m really in no hurry for it. Keep it for as long as you like.’